# Why does my output redirection not write to file?

Tags: bash, sed

I have the the following in a file called columns:

```
  SCHEMA_123 | user                      | id
  SCHEMA_123 | user                      | name
  SCHEMA_123 | user                      | role
```

I run the following and get what I'm looking for in stdout:

```
cat columns | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/|/./g'
```

Output:

```
SCHEMA_123.user.id
SCHEMA_123.user.name
SCHEMA_123.user.role
```

I'm trying to redirect the output to a file with the same filename (columns), but the file ends up empty. Here is what I am using:

```
cat columns | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/|/./g' > columns
```

If I use a different filename, I get the output I am looking for. Am I not able to read a file, modify it, and write it back out to the same filename?

Comment: Use `-i` option to inplace editing of the file `sed -i 's/ //g; s/|/./g' columns` **Caution** This would change the contents of the file

Comment: redirect to same file have unexpected result (often, empty content as output). If no  inline possibility, redirect to a temporary file than copy content or move temporary and overwrite the original (or keep abackup copy by rename it before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read and write to same file because shell will truncate the output file to zero byte even before executing the command line.

Use **inline editing** option in `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/ //g; s/|/./g' columns
```